# Getting Python error, `unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'`

Tags: python

This is the code showing unsupported operand I think this may be in thread_times variable. I get this error:

> uTypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

Why do I get `unsupported operand type(s) for 'str' and 'int'` in Python?

```
   for thread in thread_subs:
       thread_times = priority_train.index[priority_train.Subject.str.contains(str(thread), 
 regex=False) | priority_train.Subject.str.contains('re: ' + str(thread), regex=False)]

       thread_freq = len(thread_times)
       min_time = thread_times.min()
       max_time = thread_times.max()
       time_span = (max_time - min_time).seconds
       if thread_freq<2:
           thread_counts['freq'].append(np.nan)
           thread_counts['time_span'].append(np.nan)
           thread_counts['weight'].append(np.nan)
       else:
           try:
               weight = thread_freq / time_span
               log_weight = 10 + np.log10(weight)
               except ZeroDivisionError:
               log_weight = np.mean(thread_counts['weight'])
               thread_counts['freq'].append(thread_freq)
               thread_counts['time_span'].append(time_span)
               thread_counts['weight'].append(log_weight)
               #if thread_subs.index(thread)%100 ==0:
               #   print(thread_subs.index(thread)%100)
```

---

```
          TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
      <ipython-input-31-caa5f349a35d> in <module>
     4    min_time = thread_times.min()
     5    max_time = thread_times.max()
    ----> 6    time_span = (max_time - min_time).seconds
    7    if thread_freq<2:
    8        thread_counts['freq'].append(np.nan)

 TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
```

Comment: I don't see `thread_counts` defined anywhere in your code. Where has it been declared or created? Is it a dataframe?

Comment: thread_counts = {
    'freq': [],
    'time_span': [],
    'weight': []
} it is declared above th for loop

Comment: Add `print((min_time, max_time))` before the failing instruction, then show what is printed.

Comment: thread_times = priority_train.index[priority_train.Subject.str.contains(thread, regex=False) | priority_train.Subject.str.contains('re: ' + thread, regex=False)]  
    ...:     thread_freq = len(thread_times)
    ...:     min_time = thread_times.min()
    ...:     max_time = thread_times.max()
    ...:     print((min_time, max_time))
 ('2020-04-03', '2020-04-03')

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

Comment: Please [edit] your question instead of adding comments, so that you can format code and output. It's hard to read in comments. Also, not all comments may or may not be shown and usually in order of votes, not chronologically. Make it easy to help you by putting all information in one place, the question. See also [ask].

Answer (score 0):

i found the answer.see this the problem is in min and max var it give string date and string cant be substracted so i converted into date then getting differences between them.

for thread in thread_subs:

```
 thread_times=priority_train.index[priority_train.Subject.str.contains(thread, 
     regex=False) | priority_train.Subject.str.contains('re: ' + thread, regex=False)]

thread_freq = len(thread_times)
min_time1 = thread_times.min()
max_time1 = thread_times.max()
min_time=date_object = datetime.strptime(min_time1,'%Y-%m-%d').date()
max_time=date_object = datetime.strptime(max_time1,'%Y-%m-%d').date()
time_span = (max_time - min_time).seconds
if thread_freq<2:
    thread_counts['freq'].append(np.nan)
    thread_counts['time_span'].append(np.nan)
    thread_counts['weight'].append(np.nan)
else:
    try:
        weight = thread_freq / time_span
        log_weight = 10 + np.log10(weight)
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        log_weight = np.mean(thread_counts['weight'])
    thread_counts['freq'].append(thread_freq)
    thread_counts['time_span'].append(time_span)
    thread_counts['weight'].append(log_weight)
```